# Wordpress - too many templates?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I am about to start developing a site for a business and will be utilising the WordPress CMS. I haven't used WordPress much and so am inexperienced, however believe that I know enough to get the job done.

Having looked through the design supplied and mapped them across to template pages needed, I have 13 individual templates; some are for specific pages like the Home, Contact, and others are more general, for instance, a gallery template for various categories of images[image]

What I am asking in this long-winded question is this: is 13 individual template pages too much?

Comment: So you have simply customized some copies of page.php and used the new ones as new page template?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. I haven't started developing - I am more just designing a sort of schema to give myself an idea of what is being used where. I will post the schema up, not sure whether it will be of any use mind...

Comment: You may want to think about the real differences between templates - is the general layout feels different, or is it related to some block/widgets only? I recommend you to think on a post type level first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually depends on the **requirement** and the **design**,

If your project is about out of the box design then you might have some interactive ideas.So to implement those you might need some templates.

But if you have some common layouts then you can **group** them and create a **template** which it may applicable.

Eg-: single page..if all the **single pages** having the **same layout** you can use one single file rather than having many pages for each.

You can archive this easily in wordpress.

You can get more idea about [templates](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/wordpress-custom-page-templates/) from this.

Answer (score 1):

You can sometimes use a single template in place of multiple templates if they are much similar using conditions. Not exactly the conditions I am specifying  but something like:

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) {
    // This is the blog posts index
    get_sidebar( 'blog' );
} elseif(  is_front_page() ) {
    // This is not the blog posts index
    get_sidebar();
} else {
   //Something else
}
?>
```

And truly 13 templates are not too much for a website.